# Code below Throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, fxml

```
public class controller implements Initializable {

ListView<String> myList;
private Stage stage;
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4");
    myList.setItems(list);
}
...
```

I Don't understand why adding element to list throws error. 
If this is not correct way then how to add element to list dynamically.

if `//myList.setItems(list);`
then it runs.

Comment: to be honest I would have thought you would get a NPE as myList is not initialised.

Comment: it is binded with FXML

Comment: @Spock post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Oh found error ListView was not public so it wasn't able to bind and java1 you were right about NPE it was main cause.
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
...

public ListView<String> myList;
...
```

to able to access by fxml it need to be public.